# Given an array, please determine whether it contains three numbers whose sum equals to 0

Tags: java

> Given an array, please determine whether it contains three numbers whose sum equals to 0.

**Java**

I could easily think of a brute force solution

```
  public class HelloWorld {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[]arr = {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, -7, 0, -9}; 
    boolean found = false;
    for(int x = 0; x < arr.length; x++){
        for(int y = 0; y < arr.length; y++){
            for(int z = 0; z < arr.length; z++){
                if(arr[x] + arr[y] + arr[z] == 0){
                found = true;
                break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if(found){
        System.out.println("Was found");
    } else{
        System.out.println("Was not found");
    }
  }
}
```

This is clearly `O(N^3)` but how can I do better?

Comment: where is `arr2` coming from?

Comment: @PritamBanerjee, I was just doing some testing to make sure soln works

Comment: Your solution, as written, will compare numbers to themselves.  (e.g., if a[0]+a[0]+a[3] == 0.)  You probably don't want it to do that.

Comment: Your solution also will test every permutation:  E.g., after it has tested a[1]+a[2]+a[3], it will test a[2]+a[1]+a[3],  a[3]+a[2]+a[1], etc.  You probably don't want it to do that either.

Answer (score 0):

A little better solution will be:

```
    int[]arr = {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, -7, 0, -9}; 
    boolean found = false;
    for(int x = 0; x < arr.length-3; x++){
       for (int y = x+1; y < arr.length - 2; y++){
           for (int z = y+1; z < arr.length; z++){
               if(arr[x] + arr[y] + arr[z] == 0){
                   found = true;
                   break;
                   }
           }
       }
    }
    if(found){
        System.out.println("Was found");
    } else{
        System.out.println("Was not found");
    }
  }
```

You don't need to add the same number to itself again.

Hence you can use `y = x+1` and `z = y+1`.

Another better `O(n^2)` solution is something like this which uses sorting:

> ```
> class FindTriplet
> {
>
>     // returns true if there is triplet with sum equal
>     // to 'sum' present in A[]. Also, prints the triplet
>     boolean find3Numbers(int A[], int arr_size, int sum) 
>     {
>         int l, r;
>
>         /* Sort the elements */
>         quickSort(A, 0, arr_size - 1);
>
>         /* Now fix the first element one by one and find the
>            other two elements */
>         for (int i = 0; i < arr_size - 2; i++) 
>         {
>             // To find the other two elements, start two index variables
>             // from two corners of the array and move them toward each
>             // other
>             l = i + 1; // index of the first element in the remaining elements
>             r = arr_size - 1; // index of the last element
>             while (l < r) 
>             {
>                 if (A[i] + A[l] + A[r] == sum) 
>                 {
>                     System.out.print("Triplet is " + A[i] + " ," + A[l]
>                             + " ," + A[r]);
>                     return true;
>                 }
>                 else if (A[i] + A[l] + A[r] < sum)
>                     l++;
>
>                 else // A[i] + A[l] + A[r] > sum
>                     r--;
>             }
>         }
>
>         // If we reach here, then no triplet was found
>         return false;
>     }
>
>     int partition(int A[], int si, int ei) 
>     {
>         int x = A[ei];
>         int i = (si - 1);
>         int j;
>
>         for (j = si; j <= ei - 1; j++) 
>         {
>             if (A[j] <= x) 
>             {
>                 i++;
>                 int temp = A[i];
>                 A[i] = A[j];
>                 A[j] = temp;
>             }
>         }
>         int temp = A[i + 1];
>         A[i + 1] = A[ei];
>         A[ei] = temp;
>         return (i + 1);
>     }
>
>     /* Implementation of Quick Sort
>     A[] --> Array to be sorted
>     si  --> Starting index
>     ei  --> Ending index
>      */
>     void quickSort(int A[], int si, int ei) 
>     {
>         int pi;
>
>         /* Partitioning index */
>         if (si < ei) 
>         {
>             pi = partition(A, si, ei);
>             quickSort(A, si, pi - 1);
>             quickSort(A, pi + 1, ei);
>         }
>     }
>
>     // Driver program to test above functions
>     public static void main(String[] args) 
>     {
>         FindTriplet triplet = new FindTriplet();
>         int A[] = {1, 4, 45, 6, 10, 8};
>         int sum = 0;   // this is what you are looking for
>         int arr_size = A.length;
>
>         triplet.find3Numbers(A, arr_size, sum);
>     }
> }
> ```

Fort more read here:

http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-a-triplet-that-sum-to-a-given-value/

Comment: That is still `O(N^3)`.

Comment: @Andreas Yeah, it is. But still a little improvement, as it is not counting the same element.

Comment: @Andreas Updated my solution.

Comment: Why not just use `Arrays.sort()`?

Comment: @Andreas Yes, correct.